# Installing qt combined with MinGW on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, installation, mingw

I haven't managed to install qt properly on Windows after 2 hours of effort. I couldn't find the SDK version which is [linked](http://qt.nokia.com/download) in some sites instructing Qt installation. So I tried the other way. You can give me a link to download full sdk if it is still available, since it seems more easy to install with that way.

I installed Qt libraries for MinGW  and Qt Creator from [here](http://qt.nokia.com/download) 
Then I added the C:\Qt\4.8.4 to the path variable and ran configure.exe on Qt folder
 After that I installed the Qt Creator but there was no option to open a Qt Gui Project or quick project. Then from options I created a kit and chose MinGW as compiler and save the qmake path. With this change I could open a Qt Gui project but then I got  exited with code -1073741511 error on run. 
I tried this recommended  [solution](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26604-Runtime-problem-in-Release-mode/page2) but couldn't find those dll files on system32.
So i got tired and decided to ask stackoverflow. Am i missing a step in installation? Should i try to use msvc? Is it possible to use msvc with open source qt version?

Answer (score 0):

The Qt SDK that installed Qt, MinGW, Creator and other tools was created by Nokia, Digia didn't released such SDK yet (they promised one) - anyway if Qt 4.8.x (i think x is 1) is enough you can still download the SDK from [Nokia's site](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/da8df288-e615-443d-be5c-00c8a72435f8/Qt_SDK.html).

Also, you shouldn't run configure.exe - that is a tool that configures the build of Qt framework - if you want to build Qt itself, not your application using already built Qt.

As for your -1073741511 problem, that's a dll problem, either you are missing dlls or you are trying to use some incompatible dlls, as for adding to path i think the correct path to the qt dlls needed run-time are in C:\Qt\4.8.4\ **bin** (please check) and also make sure that you installed and added to path (or copy the dlls) from Qt that is built for the compiler you are actually using.

And also you will need some some dlls for MinGW run-time (again you can add the mingw_install_path\bin to path or copy the dlls from there into the same folder with your application)

Comment: I had actually added the path C:\MinGW\bin to the path before.
Installation instructions here says that I should run configure
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-win.html

Comment: That page is actually "install" the source code of Qt framework (in step 4 it tells you to build Qt), but you downloaded an already built Qt from [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads) right? (in this case you don't need configure.exe, you just need a binary that was using the same compiler you want to use). If you are building Qt from source you will need configure.exe and then run nmake (if you use Visual Studio), or mingw32-make (if you use MinGW) to actually build the Qt framework, this will take some time so do this only if you really need to build qt from source.

Comment: If you don't really need to build Qt yourself you can just download a binary of Qt 4.8.4 built with MinGW from [downloads](http://qt-project.org/downloads) and configure the "kit" with MinGW in Creator.

Comment: by only installing from binary I couldn't make qt work properly.After calling mingw32-make things got well somehow. Thank you after all